# Inserting JSON into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, json

Firstly, here's an example of the JSON I have;

```
[["AAL.L","Anglo American plc"],["ABF.L","Associated British Foods plc"],
["ADM.L","Admiral Group plc"],["ADN.L","Aberdeen Asset Management PLC"]]
```

I'm trying to get create a loop to loop through the JSON and enter it into my MySQL database. The database has the following tables:

```
ID, Symbol, Company, Timestamp
```

ID is used as an auto_increment, and timestamp makes use of `NOW()` in the MySQL statement. The issue I'm having is that all the examples I've looked at decode JSON  as a key/value pair and my JSON isn't. The examples I've been looking at are the following:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO suspiciousactivity (ID,Notes)
VALUES ('".$arr[0]['a']."','".$arr[0]['b']."')")or die(mysql_error());
```

I'm not asking for the code to be written for me, but just an idea of what to research into.

Comment: With your [plain numeric keys, iteration is easy](http://array.include-once.org/?foreach=1&assoc=1&json=%5B%5B%22AAL.L%22%2C%22Anglo+American+plc%22%5D%2C%5B%22ABF.L%22%2C%22Associated+British+Foods+plc%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%22ADM.L%22%2C%22Admiral+Group+plc%22%5D%2C%5B%22ADN.L%22%2C%22Aberdeen+Asset+Management+PLC%22%5D%5D). Also read up on database escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is just a list of lists, so you can just do something like:

```
<?php


$json ='[["AAL.L","Anglo American plc"],["ABF.L","Associated British Foods plc"],
["ADM.L","Admiral Group plc"],["ADN.L","Aberdeen Asset Management PLC"]]';

$items = json_decode($json); //Here items is an array of arrays

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item[0]; //Symbol
    echo $item[1]; //Company
    //Here would be a good place to do your insert
}

?>
```